# NStableView selected row color (remove border of NSTableView on selection)

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, nstableview, nscolor

I am using `NSTableView` for display my data. I want to remove color of selected row which by default taking `blue color`. Can i set it to `Clear color`. Is it possible??

EDIT:

how can i remove this blue border?? I have set `Clear color` to table background.

[image]
Thanks in advance..!!! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[tableView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];
```

To remove the table's blue focus ring border, select the table in your .XIB and set Focus Ring to None

Comment: Thanks It works nice..!!:) But table border is still highlighted.. Is it possible to remove that also??

Comment: @Francis: Please edit/update your answer. Since it's accepted as "correct" (but isn't), it'll be better help to those in the future to know that the OP's problem is the focus ring, not the selection highlight style. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This line should remove the ring.

`[tableView setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];`

Answer (score 0):

@Snhl
Francis McGrew said "select the table in your .XIB and set Focus Ring to None", that table's  inside the Scroll View

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick :)

[result setSelectable:NO];

Put the above code in the below method ...

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTextField *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];

    // There is no existing cell to reuse so create a new one
    if (result == nil) {

        result = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 289, 50)];
        result.identifier = @"MyView";
    }

    [result setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [result setBordered:NO];

//set selectable proeprty to NO and your blue border will disappear
[result setSelectable:NO];
 // Return the result
    return result;

}
```